# Using ASP.NET Identity with a .NET 3.5 WebForms site

Tags: webforms, asp.net-identity, asp.net-3.5

We are maintaining an internal organizational administration system written (sadly) in ASP.NET 3.5. We have recently been asked to add password management capabilities to the system, which seemed like a perfect fit for the password management features of ASP.NET Identity.

My question is, can we use ASP.NET Identity in our system, having it being written in ASP.NET 3.5?
If so, what is required to do it?
If not, are there any alternatives? We only need the password-related stuff, like length, special characters, prevent reuse of previous, say, 3 password etc.

Cheers,
ashilon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity framework is collection of nuget packages (DLL's) and the Runtime Version (minimum supporting .NET Framework) is `v4.0.30319`.

So that you could not be able to use ASP.NET identity framework on ASP.NET 3.5 which is .NET Framework 3.5.

Following packages using Runtime Version v4.0.30319

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
```

You could upgrade your project to support .NET Framework 4.0 or above and then you could be able to use asp.net identity framework.